# Proof of relativistic effects for low velocities

Tags: special-relativity

We can measure Lorentz contraction for fast moving objects, but we also assume that the contraction exists for all velocities, although it would be difficult to prove the contraction of slowly moving snail.

You might then argue that it is a situation where the model might give you an affirmative answer but that you couldn’t actually prove it. There are posts about this but I see no attempt of proof.

Here is an attempt to do that: We imagine a conveyor belt moving at the speed of a snail. On top of this moving belt we imagine another belt moving at the same speed so that a snail on the second belt would move with double speed. We then add belt upon belt until the snail on the last belt moves with half the speed of light. In this case we might prove the effect.

Would that be a proof that the effect exists for the lowest speed component, based on the symmetry of the build-up of speed in the arrangement?

Comment: The compounding of experimental uncertainties would thoroughly wash out any such attempt. Why are the standard proofs not already sufficient? Why would there be a weird inhomogenity in how Nature deals with different speeds, especially when relativity is being obeyed?

Comment: Accurate GPS requires corrections for Special Relativity and General Relativity, despite the fact that relative velocities of satellites, cars, planes, etc. are a tiny fraction of the speed of light.

Comment: Such a conveyor belt would be too expensive and consume too much power, you'd never find a sponsor for such an experiment.

Comment: I am discussing a thought experiment, not suggesting we should perform it. I now realize that one would have to assume the effect follws a smooth curve rather than an abrupt change in the effect.

Answer (score 4):

Time dilation has been directly measured at relative speeds of 10 m/s by Chou et al of the NIST, using very accurate atomic clocks. For comparison, this is the speed of a good human sprinter. So your proposed experiment is unnecessary. It also sounds impractical, as others have pointed out in the comments.

Comment: Eric Smith: _"Time dilation has been directly measured [...] by Chou et al of the NIST, using very accurate atomic clocks."_ -- Has been measured whether the clocks employed by [Chou et al.](https://physics.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22Chou%22) had been suitably accurate, **directly in the relevant trials** to which you're referring ? What is, and how do we measure, "accuracy of a clock" anyways; if not defined and determined by means of [Marzke-Wheeler clocks](https://physics.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22Marzke-Wheeler%22) ? Don't we account for time dilation, rather than measuring it ? ...

Comment: The authors are experts in metrology and their paper was peer reviewed, so there is every reason to believe their clocks are accurate enough. The "moving" clock was observed to tick slower than the "stationary" clock, I'd call that a direct observation.

Comment: Eric Smith: _"experts in metrology [...] peer reviewed,"_ -- Plenty qualified people to answer/address corresponding additional questions, as they may arise. _"so there is every reason to believe [...]"_ -- Cmp. [the other PSE](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22authority%22). _"The "moving" clock was observed to tick slower than the "stationary" clock, I'd call that a direct observation."_ -- The OP, your answer, and my comment were about **measuring** instead. If two clocks were measured running at unequal rates, were they (nevertheless) both "accurate" in Chou et al.'s sense ?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I was nor not clear enough in my question. It is a thought experiment, and the actual speed does not really matter. The question is about an argument that would show that the theory holds for all speeds.